# Django DetailView failing to find object based on SLUG

Tags: django, slug, django-class-based-views

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)     
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$',
    TagDetailView.as_view(),
    name='tag_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class TagDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Tag
    template_name = 'tag_detail_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'tag'
```

This is giving me a 404:

```
Page not found (404)
http://localhost:9999/tag/RandomTag/
No tag found matching the query
```

Why does Django fail to fetch the correct object based on the slug field?

Answer (score 4):

Django's [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) method:

> **Converts to lowercase**, removes non-word characters (alphanumerics and underscores) and converts spaces to hyphens. Also strips leading and trailing whitespace.

you are looking for a Camel Case'd tag:

```
http://localhost:9999/tag/RandomTag/
```

you need to use lowercase:

```
http://localhost:9999/tag/randomtag/  # or `random-tag` depending on the name
```

Check your DB to see exactly how the `slug` is saved

Answer (score 1):

Timmy's answer is correct in ascertaining the problem -- slugs are lowercase. He suggests you use a lowercase url. Not a bad solution... but perhaps you like the url like that?

If you want the slug to be case insensitive, set  `slug_field = 'slug__iexact'` on your view.

Comment: The slug is being saved to the DB as lowercase as it's being filtered through the `slugify` function. Unless you write your own `slugify` function, it will always be in the DB as lowercase so changing the query won't help

Comment: Yes, the slug is lowercase in the DB... **but the slug from the URL obviously isn't**. That leaves you with two choices: call `str.lower()` on the slug, or do a case insensitive query. While changing the case on the string is probably better for the DB, changing the query to be `__iexact` is trivial to write.

Comment: ... or just use the correct slug in the first place of course... as you suggested `;)`

Comment: If you are certain your slugs are stored in lowercase, I recommend lowercasing the slug before doing any db query. Using `__iexact` could be more expansive because it will cause a sequential scan if you don't have an uppercase index in the slug field.